# Is it possible for int_least16_t to be an alias for int rather than short?

Tags: c, types, integer, int, stdint

From the C99 standard, I can see that int_least16_t is guaranteed to have a width of at least 16 bits.

> **7.18.1.2 Minimum-width integer types**
>
> ...
>
> The typedef name uint_leastN_t designates an unsigned integer type with a width of at least N , such that no unsigned integer type with lesser size has at least the specified width. Thus, uint_least16_t denotes an unsigned integer type with a width of at least 16 bits.
>
> ...

From what I can tell, the standard only puts restrictions on the minimum width of the types, and not necessarily their rank. So on an architecture where int and short both have a width of 16 bits, is it possible that int_least16_t could be an alias for int, despite the fact that short has lesser rank?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> From what I can tell, the standard only puts restrictions on the
>   minimum width of the types, and not necessarily their rank. So on an
>   architecture where int and short both have a width of 16 bits, is it
>   possible that int_least16_t could be an alias for int, despite the
>   fact that short has lesser rank?

You have quoted the entirety of the relevant text of the standard.  Yes, if `short` is the same size as `int`, and there is no narrower integer type with at least 16 bits, then `int_least16_t` can be `int`.

Indeed, if an implementation supported only 64-bit integers, so that `long long int`, `long int`, `int`, and `short int` were all 64 bits, then `int_least16_t` could be `long long int`.  Or if `signed char` were 16 bits wide in that or some other implementation then `int_least16_t` could be `signed char`.  Or under some circumstances, it could be an extended signed integer type instead of any of the above.